# Variavel dentro de um array php

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

Eu tenho um foreach onde eu busco o valor e nome dos produtos, ai eu estou tentando integrar uma varial php dentro de um array do paghiper em json, para ele gerar o boleto, como eu posso fazer isso ?

Eu preciso por essa variavel `<?= $row->plano ?>` dentro da  `'items' => array(` ali na array.

Obrigado.

```
<?php foreach ($query->result() as $row) { ?>

                        <div class="col-md-6 offset-3">
                            <div class="card mb-5 mb-lg-0">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <table id="example1" style="width:100%; font-size:11px; text-align: center;" class="table table-bordered table-striped dataTable" role="grid">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr role="row" style="width:100%; text-align: center;">
                                                <th align="center" class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Pacote</th>
                                                <th align="center" class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Valor</th>
                                                <th align="center" class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Pagamento</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr role="row" style="width:100%; text-align: center;">
                                                <td style="text-align: center;"><?= $row->plano ?>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="text-align: center;">R$<?= $row->valor ?>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="text-align: center;">
                                                    Boleto<br>
                                                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/hlqK6Aj.png" width="24" height="24">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>

                                        </tbody>
                                        <tbody>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    <hr>
                                    <center>
                                        <h3 style="font-size:30px;">Termos e condições</h3>
                                    </center>
                                    <p>
                                        <div style="width: 100%; height: 200px; overflow-y: scroll; background-color:#E8E8E8; padding:5px;">
                                            1. Ao adquirir uma conta premium no Reverse Roleplay você adere automaticamente as regras abaixo citadas.
                                            <br><br>
                                            2. O Reverse Roleplay e seus gestores se reservam o direito de encerrar todas as atividades de seus servidores, a qualquer momento que se fizer necessário, sem aviso prévio.
                                            <br><br>
                                            3. Os benefícios adquiridos com a conta premium são pessoais. Você poderá transferir Trocas de Nome e Trocas de Número para personagens vinculados a mesma conta em que adquiriu os benefícios. Não é permitido a transferência de benefícios para personagens em contas diferentes, não insista!
                                            <br><br>
                                            4. Os benefícios tem duração de 30 dias corridos a partir da ativação do pacote, sujeito a interrupção por questões técnicas quando o servidor estiver offline (manutenção ou queda).
                                            <br><br>
                                            4.1 Ao adquirir uma conta premium você não está imune as punições administrativas do servidor. É dever de todos os jogadores, inclusive os jogadores premium, respeitar todas as regras. Não haverá devolução do valor pago caso você sofra alguma sanção da equipe.
                                            <br><br>
                                            4.2 Não haverá suspensão do prazo de validade dos benefícios em caso de banimento.
                                            <br><br>
                                            5. O jogador só terá direito aos benefícios listados no tópico oficial, não sendo exigível nenhuma outra vantagem ou direito perante a administração.
                                            <br><br>
                                            6. O pacote só poderá ser consumido pelo jogador no mês referente à doação, não podendo ser prorrogado ou deixado em espera para meses subsequentes.
                                            <br><br>
                                            7. Se o jogador depositar o valor referente a dois ou mais pacotes de benefícios, ele poderá indicar outros personagens para receber os benefícios de cada pacote. Os pacotes não são cumulativos.
                                            <br><br>
                                            8. São guardados os princípios da probidade e da boa fé na execução deste termos, sendo passível de revogação imediata dos benefícios em caso de descumprimento de qualquer das cláusulas.
                                            <br><br>
                                            9. Qualquer abertura de disputa/protesto/contestação para estornar o valor da compra após ter recebido os benefícios está sujeita a banimento de todas as contas do usuário.
                                            <br><br>
                                            10. Os benefícios serão creditados em até 48h úteis após a comprovação da doação pelas instituições financeiras. O personagem a receber os benefícios deve estar offline após a compra ser aprovada pelo UCP. Importunar membros da administração pedindo para que seja creditados os benefícios poderá acarretar punição in-game.
                                            <br><br>
                                            11. Estes termos poderão sofrer alterações futuras.
                                        </div>
                                    </p>
                                    <hr>



                                            <?php
                                    $data = array(
                                        'apiKey' => 'apk_46851304-DrKbqmJVsHOgYcLcBtFVLVwIaCRRNtHQ',
                                        'order_id' => '96874', // código interno do lojista para identificar a transacao.
                                        'payer_email' => 'pedrodevsteste@gmail.com',
                                        'payer_name' => 'teste', // nome completo ou razao social
                                        'payer_cpf_cnpj' => '00000000191', // cpf ou cnpj
                                        'payer_phone' => '0000000000', // fixou ou móvel
                                        'payer_street' => '',
                                        'payer_number' => '',
                                        'payer_complement' => '',
                                        'payer_district' => '',
                                        'payer_city' => 'São Paulo',
                                        'payer_state' => 'SP', // apenas sigla do estado
                                        'payer_zip_code' => '',
                                        'notification_url' => '',
                                        'discount_cents' => '0', // em centavos
                                        'shipping_price_cents' => '0', // em centavos
                                        'shipping_methods' => 'Envio Digital',
                                        'fixed_description' => true,
                                        'type_bank_slip' => 'boletoA4', // formato do boleto
                                        'days_due_date' => '4', // dias para vencimento do boleto
                                        'late_payment_fine' => '2', // Percentual de multa após vencimento.
                                        'per_day_interest' => true, // Juros após vencimento.
                                        'items' => array(
                                            array(
                                                'description' => 'pteste',
                                                'quantity' => '1',
                                                'item_id' => '12',
                                                'price_cents' => '1100'
                                            ) // em centavos
                                        ),
                                    );
                                    $data_post = json_encode($data);
                                    $url = "http://api.paghiper.com/transaction/create/";
                                    $mediaType = "application/json"; // formato da requisição
                                    $charSet = "UTF-8";
                                    $headers = array();
                                    $headers[] = "Accept: " . $mediaType;
                                    $headers[] = "Accept-Charset: " . $charSet;
                                    $headers[] = "Accept-Encoding: " . $mediaType;
                                    $headers[] = "Content-Type: " . $mediaType . ";charset=" . $charSet;
                                    $ch = curl_init();
                                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_post);
                                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
                                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                                    $result = curl_exec($ch);
                                    $json = json_decode($result, true);
                                    // captura o http code
                                    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
                                    if ($httpCode == 201) :
                                        // CÓDIGO 201 SIGNIFICA QUE O BOLETO FOI GERADO COM SUCESSO
                                        echo $result;
                                        // Exemplo de como capturar a resposta json
                                        $transaction_id = $json['create_request']['transaction_id'];
                                        $url_slip = $json['create_request']['bank_slip']['url_slip'];
                                        $digitable_line = $json['create_request']['bank_slip']['digitable_line'];
                                    else :
                                        echo $result;
                                    endif;
                                    ?>


                                </div>
                            </div>

                        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: e de onde você pega o `$row`?

Comment: da minha <?php foreach ($query->result() as $row) { ?> porem ela esta fora do <?php  ?> do paghiper

Comment: aqui está um print https://prnt.sc/r0cxe8

Comment: Cria um exemplo que possamos executar e entender, leia as dicas: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: vou colocar o codigo todo, basicamento eu tenho 2 funções de php na pagina, uma eu fiz para puxar informações do banco de dados, a outra é um php que vem direto do paghiper, eu quero pegar a variavel que eu fiz dentro da foreach e por dentro da arry do php que vem do paghiper

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Eu criei uma classe que vai te ajudar muito nesse quesito.

```html
<?php

class BoletosPh{
 /*
 $morador = $crud->select('usuarios', 'WHERE id = 1');
 $arrayChar = array(".", ",", "-", "(", ")", " ", "R", "r", "$");
 foreach ($morador as $dt){
  $DadosMorador['email'] = $dt['email'];
  $DadosMorador['nome'] = $dt['nome']; // nome completo ou razao social
  $DadosMorador['cpf_cnpj'] = str_replace($arrayChar, "", $dt['cpf']); // cpf ou cnpj
  $DadosMorador['telefone'] = str_replace($arrayChar, "", $dt['celular']); // fixou ou móvel
  $DadosMorador['rua'] = $dt['endereco'];
  $DadosMorador['numero'] = $dt['numero'];
  $DadosMorador['complemento'] = $dt['complemento'];
  $DadosMorador['bairro'] = $dt['bairro'];
  $DadosMorador['cidade'] = $dt['cidade'];
  $DadosMorador['estado'] = $dt['uf'];
  $DadosMorador['cep'] = str_replace($arrayChar, "", $dt['cep']); //somente numeros
 }
 
 $itens['produto']= "Condominio";
 $itens['quantidade']= "1";
 $itens['id_produto']= "12345";
 $itens['preco']= str_replace($arrayChar, "", $valor); //em centavos
  
 $outros['desconto'] = str_replace($arrayChar, "", $desconto),
 $outros['valor_envio'] = str_replace($arrayChar, "", $valor_envio,
 $outros['metodo_envio'] = "PAC", //Exemplo: SEDEX, SEDEX10, PAC, TRANSPORTADORA, MOTOBOY, RETIRADA NO LOCAL, etc.
 $outros['exibe_descricao'] = "true",
 $outros['dias_para_vencer'] = "5",
 $outros['dias_apos_vencimento'] = "5",
 
 
 //Buscar na tabela boletoph_lanca, na coluna nossonum que será impresso nome, e com nome da coluna do id.
 $lastNossoNum = $crud->ultimoitem('boletoph_lanca', 'nossonum', 'id');
 $nossonumero = (intval($lastNossoNum) <= 1000)?"1001":intval($lastNossoNum)+1;
 
 $GeraBoleto = $boletosPh->GeraBoleto($nossonumero, $DadosMorador, $itens);
 */
 function GeraBoleto($nossonumero, array $DadosMorador, array $produto, array $outros = null){
  $pontos = array(",", ".", "R", "r", "$", " ");
   
  $itens = array(
     array (
      'description' => $produto['produto'],
      'quantity' => $produto['quantidade'],
      'item_id' => $produto['id_produto'],
      'price_cents' => str_replace($pontos, "", $produto['preco'])
     ), 
    );
  $data = array(
   'apiKey' => $_SESSION['PH_APIKEY'],
   'order_id' => $nossonumero,
   'payer_email' => $DadosMorador['email'],
   'payer_name' => $DadosMorador['nome'], 
   'payer_cpf_cnpj' => $DadosMorador['cpf_cnpj'], 
   'payer_phone' => (isset($DadosMorador['telefone'])) ? $DadosMorador['telefone'] : '', 
   'payer_street' => (isset($DadosMorador['rua'])) ? $DadosMorador['rua'] : '',
   'payer_number' => (isset($DadosMorador['numero'])) ? $DadosMorador['numero'] : '',
   'payer_complement' => (isset($DadosMorador['complemento'])) ? $DadosMorador['complemento'] : '',
   'payer_district' => (isset($DadosMorador['bairro'])) ? $DadosMorador['bairro'] : '',
   'payer_city' => (isset($DadosMorador['cidade'])) ? $DadosMorador['cidade'] : '',
   'payer_state' => (isset($DadosMorador['estado'])) ? $DadosMorador['estado'] : '', // apenas sigla do estado
   'payer_zip_code' => (isset($DadosMorador['cep'])) ? $DadosMorador['cep'] : '',
   'fixed_description' => ($outros != null) ? $outros['exibe_descricao'] : "true", //frase pré configurada no painel do PagHiper
   'discount_cents' => ($outros != null) ? str_replace($pontos, "", $outros['desconto']) : "0", // em centavos
   'shipping_price_cents' => ($outros != null) ? str_replace($pontos, "", $outros['valor_envio']) : "0", // em centavos
   'shipping_methods' => ($outros != null) ? $outros['metodo_envio'] : "PAC",
   'type_bank_slip' => "boletoA4", 
   'days_due_date' => ($outros != null) ? $outros['dias_para_vencer'] : "5", 
   'late_payment_fine' => "2",
   'per_day_interest' => "true",
   'open_after_day_due' => ($outros != null) ? $outros['dias_apos_vencimento'] : "5", //Número máximo de dias em que o boleto poderá ser pago após o vencimento.
   'items' => $itens,
  );
  $data_post = json_encode( $data );
  $url = "http://api.paghiper.com/transaction/create/";
  $mediaType = "application/json"; // formato da requisição
  $charSet = "UTF-8";
  $headers = array();
  $headers[] = "Accept: ".$mediaType;
  $headers[] = "Accept-Charset: ".$charSet;
  $headers[] = "Accept-Encoding: ".$mediaType;
  $headers[] = "Content-Type: ".$mediaType.";charset=".$charSet;
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_post);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  $json = json_decode($result, true);
  // captura o http code
  $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  if($httpCode == 201):
   $boleto['transaction_id'] = $json['create_request']['transaction_id'];
   $boleto['url_slip'] = $json['create_request']['bank_slip']['url_slip'];
   $boleto['digitable_line'] = $json['create_request']['bank_slip']['digitable_line'];
   $boleto['data_venc'] = $json['create_request']['due_date'];
   $boleto['valor'] = $json['create_request']['value_cents'];
   $boleto['status'] = $json['create_request']['status'];
   $boleto['order_id'] = $json['create_request']['order_id'];
   $boleto['created_date'] = $json['create_request']['created_date'];

   $ex = explode('/', $boleto['url_slip']);
   $boleto['nosso_numero'] = $ex[count($ex)-1];

   return($boleto);
  else:
   return("Não foi possível criar o boleto");
  endif;
 }
 /*
 $transaction_id="D5ZJP1WKV37IFGOK";
 Exemplo:
 Consulta= $boletosPh->StatusBoleto($apiKey, $token, $transaction_id);
 Cancelamento= $boletosPh->StatusBoleto($token, $transaction_id, true);
 
 status pode ser:
 pending= aguardando
 canceled= cancelado
 completed= completo
 paid=  aprovado
 processing= analise
 refunded= estornado
 */
 function StatusBoleto($transaction_id, $cancelar=false){  
  if($cancelar == true):
   $data = array(
   'apiKey' => $_SESSION['PH_APIKEY'],
   'token' => $_SESSION['PH_TOKEN'],
   'status' => "canceled",
   'transaction_id' => $transaction_id,
   );
   $data_post = json_encode( $data );
   $url = "https://api.paghiper.com/transaction/cancel/";
  
  else:
   $data = array(
   'apiKey' => $_SESSION['PH_APIKEY'],
   'token' => $_SESSION['PH_TOKEN'],
   'transaction_id' => $transaction_id,
   );
   $data_post = json_encode( $data );
   $url = "https://api.paghiper.com/transaction/status/";
  endif;
  //Configuracao do cabecalho da requisicao
  $mediaType = "application/json";
  $charSet = "UTF-8";
  $headers = array();
  $headers[] = "Accept: ".$mediaType;
  $headers[] = "Accept-Charset: ".$charSet;
  $headers[] = "Accept-Encoding: ".$mediaType;
  $headers[] = "Content-Type: ".$mediaType.";charset=".$charSet;
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_post);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  $json = json_decode($result, true);
  ### captura o http code
  $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  if($httpCode == 201): // CÓDIGO 201 SIGNIFICA QUE O BOLETO FOI GERADO COM SUCESSO
   if($cancelar == false):
    $boleto['result'] = $json['status_request']['result']; //Campo que identifica se houve êxito na busca e se os parâmetros estão corretos. Esperado: success ou reject
    $boleto['response_message'] = $json['status_request']['response_message'];
    $boleto['order_id'] = $json['status_request']['order_id'];
    $boleto['status'] = $json['status_request']['status'];
    $boleto['status_date'] = $json['status_request']['status_date']; //Data da ultima alteração de status Exemplo esperado: 2017-07-14 21:21:02
    $boleto['due_date'] = $json['status_request']['due_date']; //Data do vencimento do boleto Exemplo esperado 2017-07-12
    $boleto['value_cents'] = $json['status_request']['value_cents'];
    $boleto['late_payment_fine'] = $json['status_request']['late_payment_fine']; //Esse campo só será retornado se na requisição do Boleto foi configurado a opção Multa
    $boleto['per_day_interest'] = $json['status_request']['per_day_interest']; //Esse campo só será retornado se na requisição do Boleto foi configurado a opção Juros
    $boleto['open_after_day_due'] = $json['status_request']['open_after_day_due']; //Número máximo de dias em que o boleto poderá ser pago após o vencimento.
    $boleto['digitable_line'] = $json['status_request']['bank_slip']['digitable_line'];
    $boleto['url_slip'] = $json['status_request']['bank_slip']['url_slip'];
    $boleto['http_code'] = $json['status_request']['http_code'];

    $ex = explode('/', $boleto['url_slip']);
    $boleto['nosso_numero'] = $ex[count($ex)-1];

    return($boleto);
   else:
    if($cancelar == false):
     return ($json['status_request']['response_message']);
    else:
     return ($json['cancellation_request']['response_message']);
    endif;
   endif;
  else:
   if($cancelar == false):
     return ($json['status_request']['response_message']);
    else:
     return ($json['cancellation_request']['response_message']);
    endif;
  endif;
 }
}
```